# Selenium Webdriver not clicking on element

Tags: python, html, css, selenium

I am setting up webdrivers to scrape reporting numbers from a couple of sites I use at work. All of them are password protected which hasn't been a problem until now. Here is the login screen I am trying to interact with:

https://ssp.vertamedia.com/

I am using the Selenium webdriver with Python 3.6 in Firefox.

With this site, the webdriver needs to input the user name, then interact with the "next" button before the password input and submit button are visible. I am able to fill in the username, but so far have not been able to get the webdriver to interact with the "next" button.

Below is a snippet of the button html from the site:

```
<a class="x-btn attached-btn blue x-unselectable x-box-item x-btn-attached-btn-small x-item-disabled x-btn-disabled" style="height: 40px; right: auto; left: 282px; top: 0px; margin: 0px;" hidefocus="on" unselectable="on" role="button" aria-hidden="false" aria-disabled="true" id="button-1021" data-componentid="button-1021">
    <span id="button-1021-btnWrap" data-ref="btnWrap" role="presentation" unselectable="on" style="" class="x-btn-wrap x-btn-wrap-attached-btn-small ">
        <span id="button-1021-btnEl" data-ref="btnEl" role="presentation" unselectable="on" style="height:auto;" class="x-btn-button x-btn-button-attached-btn-small x-btn-text    x-btn-button-center ">
            <span id="button-1021-btnIconEl" data-ref="btnIconEl" role="presentation" unselectable="on" class="x-btn-icon-el x-btn-icon-el-attached-btn-small  " style=""></span>
            <span id="button-1021-btnInnerEl" data-ref="btnInnerEl" unselectable="on" class="x-btn-inner x-btn-inner-attached-btn-small">next</span>
        </span>
    </span>
</a>
```

I have tried using class name, id, and css Selector and so far haven't been successful. Below is the python snippet:

```
def exe(self):
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 15)
    yesterday = date.today() - timedelta(1)
    browser.get("https://ssp.vertamedia.com")

    try:
        userElement = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,'textfield-1020-inputEl')))
        userElement.send_keys(self.cred.pop('User'))
        browser.find_element_by_id('button-1021').click()
        passElement = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'textfield-1027-inputEl')))
        passElement.send_keys(self.cred.pop('Password'))
        browser.find_element_by_id('button-1028').click()

    except TimeoutException:
        self.cred['Impression'] = "Login error"
        self.cred['Revenue'] = "Login error"
        self.cred['Date'] = yesterday.strftime('%m%d%y')
```

Essentially when it hits the passElement section where I am inputting the password, it hits an "Element is not visible" error.

Any suggestions on how to get it to interact with the next button would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried sleeping a little longer after setting the user name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should avoid using time.sleep(), and use WebDriverWait which let you wait for certain condition to occur before proceeding further :

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

def exe():
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    wait    = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    browser.get("https://ssp.vertamedia.com")
    try:
        userElement = browser.find_element_by_id('textfield-1020-inputEl')
        userElement.send_keys(self.cred.pop('User'))
        browser.find_element_by_id('button-1021').click()
        passElement = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,'textfield-1027-inputEl'))
        passElement.send_keys(self.cred.pop('Password'))
        browser.find_element_by_id('button-1028').click()
        time.sleep(10)  #Change this to WebDriverWait as well
```

You can learn more about selenium waits here : http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Comment: Thanks SDBot, I appreciated the link to the waits section and this improved all the other drivers I have set up. What I have happening now is it is timing out. 

For something reason it isn't "clicking" on the next button. A sample username can be test@sample.com. I am wondering if there is a better way to interact with the page besides click()

Comment: @Andrew is the issue not solved yet? you can try to use javascript click ex: `browser.execute_script("document.getElementById('button-1028-btnInnerEl').click()")` and also have you tried using expected conditions `element_to_be_clickable`?

Comment: I tried element_to_be_clickable as well as a couple of the other expected conditions. I managed to get it working reliably with a mix of wait() and time.sleep()

Answer (score 0):

Thanks again to SDBot for the help with wait().

With this particular site, something weird happens and the driver isn't able to tell that the "next" button is visible and ready to be clicked on. The same thing happens with the "login" button. I managed to get it working by inserting time.sleep() again between filling in the user name and login. I tried several different expected conditions but wasn't able to get it to work. http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=expected%20conditions#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it

```
def exe(self):
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 15)
    yesterday = date.today() - timedelta(1)
    browser.get("https://ssp.vertamedia.com")

    try:
        userElement = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,'textfield-1020-inputEl')))
        userElement.send_keys(self.cred.pop('User'))
        time.sleep(# insert seconds)
        wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,'button-1021-btnInnerEl'))).click()
        passElement = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'textfield-1027-inputEl')))
        passElement.send_keys(self.cred.pop('Password'))
        time.sleep(# insert seconds5)
        wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,'button-1028'))).click()

    except TimeoutException:
        self.cred['Impression'] = "Login error"
        self.cred['Revenue'] = "Login error"
        self.cred['Date'] = yesterday.strftime('%m%d%y')
```